# how to manage '\' in python, while loading psv to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I am just loading csv file into postgres using python.

I think that the problem is because there is a \ on the psv file. here is my code.

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import string

# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=xxxx")

cur = conn.cursor()

# create a table
 cur.execute("CREATE TABLE ADDRESS_SITE (ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY, DATE_CREATED Date,\
#   DATE_RETIRED Date, ADDRESS_TYPE varchar(8), ADDRESS_SITE_NAME varchar(45));")

file = open("/Users/jubertroldan/GNAF/AUG17_GNAF_PipeSeparatedValue_20170821153434/G-NAF/G-NAF AUGUST 2017/Standard/NSW_ADDRESS_SITE_psv.psv","r")

with file as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        print(f.readline().count('|'))
        print(f.readline())
        cur.copy_from(f, 'ADDRESS_SITE', sep="|",null = '')
        conn.commit()
file.close()
```

here is the code!

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GNAF_ADDRESS_SITE.py", line 43, in <module>
    cur.copy_from(f, 'ADDRESS_SITE', sep="|",null = '')
psycopg2.DataError: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY address_site, line 1379807: "713005737|2015-04-28||UN|EASEMENT FOR OVERHANG 0.7 WIDE\
701367558|2004-02-23||UN|"
```

here is the line on the PSV file i am trying to load that has error. (see below)

```
01367554|2004-02-23||UN|
701367555|2004-02-23||UN|
701367556|2004-02-23||UN|
713005737|2015-04-28||UN|EASEMENT FOR OVERHANG 0.7 WIDE\
701367558|2004-02-23||UN|
701367559|2004-02-23||UN|
701367560|2004-02-23||UN|
```

i guess the problem is the "\" on the data.

question is how do i manage that? how do i remove that during the read process? whats the best way to fix it?

thanks!

Comment: Looking at the error message, the backslash character causes two lines to be merged into one (look at the two numbers ending with 737 and 558).  If this problem is only in one line, the simplest solution is to edit the data file with a text editor, and remove the backslash character.  If the problem occurs repeatedly (in many lines or in many files), you can open the file, read it one line at a time, use the `.replace('\\','')` method to remove the backslash, and write it to another temporary file.  Then use the temporary file.

Comment: thanks, i tried adding the .replace in f..however the error is \n Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GNAF_ADDRESS_SITE.py", line 44, in <module>
    cur.copy_from(f.replace('\\',''), 'ADDRESS_SITE', sep="|",null = '')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: i modified it like this : cur.copy_from(f.replace('\\',''), 'ADDRESS_SITE', sep="|",null = '')

Comment: ended up manually deleting the \ in the data file..will solve this next time - keeping the question open thanks

Comment: `cur.copy_expert()` may be able to tell postgresql the correct way to interpret that stream.